# Minimum action date for specific critera

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

I am new to PeopleSoft querying and only have the ability to work in query manager, so I can't write just SQL, but have to use expressions. I am having issues building a query where I want to have a column of data that shows a minimum action date for specific criteria.

So far I have this for an expression:
CASE WHEN F.ACTION = 'REH' AND F.ACTION_DT > D.TERMINATION_DT 
THEN F.ACTION_DT 
ELSE NULL
END

But what I really need is the minimum Action Date that satisfies the F.ACTION = 'REH' requirement and F.ACTION > D.TERMINATION_DT. Right now I get a bunch of rows with the same information like ID, Term date and term reason with more than one action date because many of the action dates are greater than the termination dates. I just want to show the smallest, but can't figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out by just keeping that, but marking the field as minimum in the Field section instead of trying to write the code (when I was I got a group by error).